# Add trigger to form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have been working on a simple "Time off request" form using Google Apps.  The I have associated a script with the form which detects the respondents' supervisor and sends them a link to a new form for their approval.

Here is the code  from the script I used to create the new form.

```
//create approval form as part of the Message Creation process.
var approvalForm = FormApp.create("Approve Days off Request")
approvalForm.setTitle("Approval form for " + user.Name)
// truncated ...

var approvalItem = approvalForm.addMultipleChoiceItem(); //Item on First Page
var disapproveReasonPage = approvalForm.addPageBreakItem(); //Page Break Item
var disapproveReason = approvalForm.addParagraphTextItem(); //Item on Second Page
// truncated ...

//Question 1, Page 1
approvalItem.setTitle(user.Name + " has requested " + daysOff + " day(s) off starting on " + firstDate+".") 
approvalItem.setHelpText("Would you like to approve this request?")
approvalItem.setRequired(true);      
approvalItem.setChoices ([
  approvalItem.createChoice('Yes', FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT),
  approvalItem.createChoice('No', FormApp.PageNavigationType.CONTINUE)
]);
//Question 2, Page 2
disapproveReason.setTitle("Would you like to give a reason?");
disapproveReason.setHelpText("Optional")
disapproveReasonPage.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT)
```

Then a link is generated and sent to the supervisor to approve the request.
I am wanting to add a trigger to the form created above (approvalForm).  I would imagine that there is a way, but haven't been able to find the greatest documentation on it.  The closest I've come is [TriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder.html) Class.  I tried creating one associated to the target form with

```
var approveScript = ScriptApp.newTrigger('Approval')
.forForm(approvalForm.getId())
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
```

but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted it.  I did have a function named Approval just to see if I could manipulate the form with it

```
function Approval(){
$form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `$form` instead of `approvalForm` variable?

Comment: in another place in the Approval() I had defined `$form` with `var $form = DocsList.getFileById(approvalForm.getId())`.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was originally being added as a container bound script.  Changing it to a Standalone installable script fixed this problem. Hopefully this answer will be to someone else having a similar issue.